# Grails - Prevent XSS when retrieving i18n messages

Tags: javascript, grails, xss

I am using messageSource to access i18n properties in the service layer to provide user feedback when an error has occurred;

messageSource.getMessage('validation.my.code', args, defaultLocale).

The results are pushed into the flash scope (info or error) and returned to the browser as json and process in jQuery as below;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
        showMessage({info: data.info, error: data.error});
    }
})
```

My problem is that when the arg passed to messageSource is displaying user input, for example "'johndoe' username is already taken", there is potential for an XSS attack.
My encoding in Config.groovy is set as follows as it breaks other parts of the application if any stricter.

```
codecs {
  expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
  scriptlet = 'none' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
  taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
  staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
}
```

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way of dealing with escaping the json being returned without having to hand roll my own solution.

**EDIT: more detail**

The above is attacked by simply putting the following into the relevant input field on a UI form:

```
<script>alert('hello');</script>
```

Validation occurs in the service layer by means of the following method;

```
private List<String> validate(def domainObject) {
    def messages = []
    if (!domainObject.validate()) {
       messages = domainObject.errors.allErrors.collect {
       // the error objects implement MessageSourceResolvable  
       simpleMessageSource.getMessage(it, args, defaultLocale)   
    }
    messages
}
```

the input is passed into the args method to become part of the error string returned to the user and is eventually output back to the browser as json.
This of course culminates in a JavaScript popup saying "hello".

Comment: could you please also add, how you attacked this

Answer (score 0):

Regarding docs: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/guide/security.html grails by default denied XSS atacks by decoding input values

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are pointing me to, can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess by this you mean that Grails already has built in mechanisms to sanitise data that is reflected back to the user, which can be configured in Config.groovy. But as mentioned in the question, I have to keep these settings quite lenient based on my applications requirements.

Comment: you can denied this option and use "".encodeAsURL() as I remember it should help you or removeAll(inputString, "<script>"). You can play with it. Hope I understand you well.